# Themes for python e-commerce solutions

Tags: python, e-commerce

There are two good open source python e-commerce solutions exist: Satchmo and LFS. But I can't find any theme for them. Does at least one open source theme for them exist? There are thousands themes for Magento, osCommerce, OpenCart, but zero themes for Satchmo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well, if that is the case, I think the only reason I can think up of is that this Satchmo is not that popular so that nobody is willing to port or design a theme for it.

I would suggest randomly grab a theme, port it here accordingly